# How to derive hyperbolic tangent from SIR model's Recovered with Partial fraction decomposition approach

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

There are follow SIR model's ODE:

\begin{eqnarray}
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{dS}{dt} &=& -rSI & (1)\\
\frac{dI}{dt} &=& rSI - \gamma I & (2)\\
\frac{dR}{dt} &=& \gamma I & (3)\\
I + S + R &=& N, \text{ constant} & (4)
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}

- *infectives*, say $I$,
- *susceptibles*, say $S$
- *removals(recovered)*, say $R$.

determine $dR/dt$ as a function of time, $t$ .

from (3) and (4)
$$
\frac{dR}{dt}
= \gamma (N - R - S), (5)
$$

we can determine $S$ as a function of $R$ from

$$
\frac{dS}{dR}
= \frac{dS/dt}{dR/dt}
= -\frac{rSI}{\gamma I} 
= -\frac{S}{\rho}
$$

Solving for $S$ gives $S = S_0 e^{-R/\rho}, \rho=\gamma/r$, and substituting in (5) gives

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dR}{dt} = \gamma(N - R - S_0e^{-R/\rho}), (6)
\end{eqnarray}

assuming $R / \rho$ is reasonably small, from 2nd order taylor

$$
e^{-R / \rho} \simeq 1 - R/\rho + (R / \rho)^2 / 2 - \cdots
$$

$$
\frac{dR}{dt} = \gamma[ N - R - S_0(1 - R/\rho + R^2 / 2\rho^2) ]\\
$$

i.e.

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dR}{dt}
= \gamma [ N - S_0 + (S_0 / \rho - 1)R - S_0R^2/2\rho^2 ], (7)
\end{eqnarray}

It can be verified that this equation has solution,

$$
\frac{dR}{S_0/(2\rho^2)R^2 +(1 - S_0 / \rho)R + (S_0-N)} = -\gamma dt\\
\frac{2\rho^2}{S_0}\frac{dR}{R^2 + \frac{2\rho^2}{S_0}(1 - S_0 / \rho)R + \frac{2\rho^2}{S_0}(S_0-N)} = -\gamma dt\\
$$

calc roots for Partial fraction decomposition.

\begin{eqnarray*}
r 
&=& \frac{- \frac{2\rho^2}{S_0}(1 - S_0 / \rho) \pm \sqrt{\frac{4\rho^4}{S_0^2}(1 - S_0 / \rho)^2 - 4\frac{2\rho^2}{S_0}(S_0-N)}}{2}\\
&=& \frac{- \frac{2\rho^2}{S_0}(1 - S_0 / \rho) \pm 
\sqrt{\frac{4\rho^4}{S_0^2}\{(1 - S_0 / \rho)^2 - 2\frac{S_0}{\rho^2}(S_0 - N ) \}}  }{2}\\
&=& \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}\{ (S_0 / \rho - 1) \pm 
\sqrt{(1 - S_0 / \rho)^2 - 2\frac{S_0}{\rho^2}(S_0 - N ) } \}\\
&=& \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}\{ (S_0 / \rho - 1) \pm 
\sqrt{(1 - S_0 / \rho)^2 + 2\frac{S_0}{\rho^2}( N - S_0) } \}\\
&=& \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}( \pm \alpha + \beta )\\
\end{eqnarray*}

where

$$
\alpha = \sqrt{(1 - S_0 / \rho)^2 + 2\frac{S_0}{\rho^2}( N - S_0) } \\
\beta = (S_0 / \rho - 1)\\
$$

roots are:

$$
r_1 = \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}( +\alpha + \beta )\\
r_2 = \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}( -\alpha + \beta )\\
$$

do Partial fraction decomposition,

$$
\frac{2\rho^2}{S_0}\frac{dR}{(R-r_1)(R-r_2)} = -\gamma dt\\
\frac{2\rho^2}{S_0} \int \frac{1}{r_1-r_2} (\frac{1}{(R-r_1)} - \frac{1}{(R-r_2)}) dR = - \int \gamma dt\\
$$

from $r_1 - r_2 = \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}2\alpha$,

$$
\frac{1}{\alpha} \int (\frac{1}{(R-r_1)} - \frac{1}{(R-r_2)}) dR = -\int \gamma dt\\
\ln{(R-r_1)} - \ln{(R-r_2)} = - \alpha \gamma t + \phi\\
\ln{\frac{R-r_1}{R-r_2}} = - \alpha \gamma t + \phi\\
\frac{R - r_1}{R - r_2} = e^{-\alpha \gamma t + \phi}\\
R - r_1 = (R - r_2)e^{-\alpha \gamma t + \phi}\\
(1-e^{-\alpha \gamma t + \phi})R = r_1  - r_2 e^{-\alpha \gamma t + \phi}\\
R = \frac{ r_1  - r_2 e^{-\alpha \gamma t + \phi}}{1-e^{-\alpha \gamma t + \phi}}\\
$$

substituting $r_1, r_2$,

\begin{eqnarray*}
R 
&=& \frac{ \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}(\alpha + \beta)  - \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}(-\alpha + \beta) e^{ -\alpha \gamma t + \phi}}{1-e^{-\alpha \gamma t + \phi}}\\
&=& \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}\frac{ \alpha(1 + e^{ - \alpha \gamma t + \phi}) + \beta(1-e^{ \alpha \gamma t + \phi}) }{1-e^{- \alpha \gamma t + \phi}}\\
&=& \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}\left( \beta + \frac{ \alpha(1+e^{- (\alpha \gamma t - \phi)})}{1-e^{- (\alpha \gamma t - \phi)}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

from
$$
\tanh{x/2} = \frac{1-e^{-x}}{1+e^{-x}}\\
$$

\begin{eqnarray*}
R 
&=& \frac{\rho^2}{S_0}\left( \beta + \frac{ \alpha}{\tanh{(\frac{\alpha \gamma t}{2} - \phi')}}\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

actually, should be hyperperbolic tangnt (not Reciprocal),
how to derive hyperperbolic tangnt?

> original paper:
>
> - https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/pdf/10.1098/rspa.1927.0118

Comment: Any chance that paper is wrong?

Comment: probably not. without  partial fraction decomposition, from $\int 1/(ax^2+bx+c) dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{4ac - b^2}} 2\tan^{-1}{[\frac{2ax + b}{\sqrt{4ac - b^2}}]}$, to $\tan{\left[ \frac{\sqrt{4ac - b^2}}{2}\int \frac{1}{ax^{2}+bx+c} dx \right]} = \frac{2ax + b}{\sqrt{4ac - b^2}}$, then using $-i\tan{ix} = \frac{e^{x}-e^{-x}}{(e^{-x} + e^{x})}=\tanh{x}$, appear hyperbolic tangent.